# Can I use an if statement inside an if statement

Tags: if-statement

Is it possible to use an if statement inside of an if statement?
For example:

```
If answer=10:
     answer2=input("Do you agree")
     if answer2=yes
         print("You agree")
     else: 
         print("You disagree")


else:
print("You don't answer")
```

Comment: Yes. You can nest them

Comment: Add the language tag. Your code looks like Python, but the syntax is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

For your question of an if statement in an if statement you would use a ternary operation:

```
if((condition1) ? condition2 : condition3)
   code to execute
```

But I think you asked your question wrong. From your example, if answer = 10 you want to prompt the user for something and then do something different based on their response.  It is hard to really tell you how to implement that without knowing what language you are writing this in but most languages have some way of creating a "code block", generally like this:

```
if(condition1)
{
   if(condition2)
      docode;
   else
      docode;
}
else
   docode;
```

although some languages just us indentation